# It is possible to determine for hacker whether a directory in the project exists or not in IIS. How I can avoid this?

Tags: iis, web-config

It is possible to determine hacker whether a directory in the project exists or not.

If I disabled directory browsing in IIS, this link throws a different error which is enough to discover whether the directory exists or not.

`https://www.website.com/admin/` (Error 403)

`https://www.website.com/admindoesnotexist/`  (Error 404)

Can we just throw 403 instead of 404?

Comment: Can you hire an experienced security professional and learn from there? This has nothing to do with programming and web server security is a huge topic.  You shouldn’t expect a place like here can give you the actual guidance.

Comment: Refer to this official doc of Custom Error Options: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/diagnosing-http-errors/how-to-use-http-detailed-errors-in-iis#custom-error-options. May you can also refer to Preventing Web-based Directory Enumeration Attacks: https://pentestmonkey.net/blog/direnum.

Comment: This is the exact place I can get guidance. My tags are very clear,